# EJS HTML Render With Greater Than (>) Symbol

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

**After I go to the root route the h1 and paragraph get rendered but it renders with > Symbol Any Solution I am following a course and in that course the instructor does all the following process and get the desired output but it does not have > Symbol  **

```js
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const ejs = require("ejs");
var posts = [];
const app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.get("/", function(req, res){
  res.render("home", {Content : homeStartingContent, posts: posts});
  
});
app.get("/compose", function(req, res){
  res.render("compose");
});

app.post("/compose",bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}),function(req, res){
  let Post = {
    PostTitle: req.body.Title,
    Content: req.body.Content, 
  };
  posts.push(Post);
  res.redirect("/");
  
});


app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.static("public"));

app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log("Server started on port 3000");
});
```

```html
<%- include("Partials/header") %>

<h1>Home</h1>
<p><%= Content %></p>



    <% posts.forEach(function(post){ %>
    <h1>><%=post.PostTitle%></h1> 
    <p>><%=post.Content%></p> 
 <%   }); %>


<%- include("Partials/footer") %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have included `>` mistakenly.
It should be

```
<h1><%=post.PostTitle%></h1> 
<p><%=post.Content%></p>
```

not

```
<h1>><%=post.PostTitle%></h1> 
<p>><%=post.Content%></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

here is your problem

<% posts.forEach(function(post){ %>

```
<h1>><%=post.PostTitle%></h1>
    ^ 
<p>><%=post.Content%></p>
```

<%   }); %>